# Invalid Indirect Reference 0x2bc70b08

Tags: java, android

I am using vitamio api to play my audio files.
on the official website of vitamio, using it is the same as using the native MediaPlayer in android.

My audio played for a few seconds until it crashes.
In my logcat there is an error report :

`Invalid indirect reference 0x2bc70b08 in decodeIndirectRef`
`VM aborting`
`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)`

Can anyone help me fix this? Please.